# Files are the same despite replacing the output of one

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem:**
I am using python to try and randomize Geometry Dash images. They are stored in large png files (Called `GJ_GameSheetX`, with x being a number between 1 and 4) which display most of the images. They go along with a .plist file which says where each image is in the GameSheet file. I am using python to (try and) randomize where the plist file says they are located - but the output file is the same as the unchanged one.
**Code:**

```
import random

# os.system("dir /b \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Geometry Dash\\Resources\" > directories.txt")
# Unnecessary dir

def wal(l, n):
    with open(fr"GameFiles\Finals\GS_{n}.txt", "w") as ff:
        ff.writelines(l)


for i in range(4):
    ii = "0" + str(i + 1)
    if ii == "01": ii = ""
    os.system(f"xcopy \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\steamapps\\common\\Geometry Dash\\Resources\\GJ_GameSheet{ii}.plist\" GameFiles /Y")
    with open(f"GameFiles\\GJ_GameSheet{ii}.plist", "r") as f:
        text_nosplit = str(f.read())
        ftext = text_nosplit.replace("\\n", "").replace(" ", "")
        ftext = ftext.split("</string>")

        for _ in range(5): # Recurses a few times to clear out the list properly.
            for x in range(len(ftext)):
                try:
                    if not ftext[x][0:4] == "<key>" or "smartupdate" in ftext[x]: ftext.pop(x)
                    try:
                        ftext[x].index("}}")
                        ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("}}", "}}</string>")
                    except ValueError:
                        ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("}", "}</string>")
                except IndexError:
                    break
        for x in range(len(ftext) - 1):
            l = ftext[x].index("<key")
            le = l + 1
            while ftext[x][le] != "<":
                le += 1
            ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace(ftext[x][l : le + 6], "")
            if ftext[x][-1] == "}":
                ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("}", "}</string>")
            ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("<string>", "")
            ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("</string>", "")
            ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace("\n", "")
            ftext[x] = ftext[x].replace(" ", "")
        with open(fr"GameFiles\Finals\GS_{ii}.txt", "w") as ff:
            repls = []
            t_shuffled = random.sample(ftext, len(ftext))
            for n, i in enumerate(ftext):
                text_nosplit.replace(i, t_shuffled[n])
                if (n == len(ftext) - 1):   wal(text_nosplit, ii)
```

Comment: *but the output file is the same as the unchanged one* -- so you are observing that the existing files `GameFiles\Finals\GS_{n}.txt` do not change after running your program?

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more clear - by the unchanged file I meant the one which I use xcopy on at the start - GJ_Gamesheet{ii}.

Comment: And no - they do not change

Comment: ok so you're observing that `GJ_Gamesheet{ii}` does not update and you expected it to?  Sorry man there's 3 open files and I really don't know what is not working from what you wrote.

Comment: No - I expect `GameFiles\Finals\GS_{n}.txt` to change.

Comment: I see that you are opening that file for "w" and then on the very last line calling `wal` which again opens that same file for "w".   I am unsure of whether it is safe to use `with` in a re-entrant way.  Maybe it works?  However, I would have expected the previous lines to work.  Could you add a `print('test')` preceding `with open(fr"GameFiles\Finals\GS_{ii}.txt", "w") as ff:` just so we are 100% sure it is reaching your code that matters?

Comment: The tests worked.

Comment: Can you delete the output files, then rerun.  You would expect them to regenerate, yes?  If they don't, issue with file writing.  If they do, issue with algorithm.

Comment: they regenerated.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you were asking.  From the title I inferred that your issue was *file was not changing* instead of *algorithm not working*.  For these questions to have the most benefit to future readers it is helpful to produce a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  As such you have a lot of extraneous code here that is obscuring, and we do not have data to reproduce easily.